# returnUrl redirecting to wrong page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For some reason my application keeps trying to find the Home Controller when redirecting back to the returnUrl (through the AccountController Login Action) even though I've changed my HomeController to be called DashboardController as well as having changed my RouteConfig.cs

```
namespace application
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

When my application starts it automatically is redirected to the Account/Login view due to an `[Authorize]` attribute in the controllers. But when I hand type in Account/Login into my Url the returnUrl becomes equal to "/" in the GET action, and upon signing in I receive a 404 error for missing page since it can't find HomeController Index View (which is actually DashboardController Index View).

What else do I need to change so that my application no longer searches for a Home Controller?

Comment: In your AccountController, do you `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")` after successful login by any chance?

Comment: No, it is using a "case SignInStatus.Success: return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);" And the returnUrl is equal to a forward slash

Comment: And what is implemented in the `RedirectToLocal` method? 
Have you tried code stepping to see what happens after log in?

Comment: I've already performed all the elementary debugging and syntax checking steps. The local is where the returnUrl equals to "/" instead of "Dashboard/Index"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that the Account Controller RedirectToLocal action was redirecting to the Home Controller Index Action so I had to change it to Dashboard Controller Index Action.

```
private ActionResult RedirectToLocal(string returnUrl)
    {
        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That controller action will typically look for the file Index.cshtml in the "~/Views/Dashboard" folder. If you did not rename the "~/Views/Home" folder to "~/Views/Dashboard", the controller will be looking in the wrong place for the file and will not be able to find it, therefore producing the 404 error.

Comment: I already renamed my views folder from Home to Dashboard during the initial change

Comment: Could you explicitly declare an empty route? 

`routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Home",
        url: "",
        defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index" }
    );`

in RouteConfig.cs?